# Azure file copy task creating additional folder structure while copying files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, cicd

I have a release pipeline that expects files to be copied from source to target. Target is an Azure storage container(no folder hierarchy inside it.)

Somehow, Azure file copy is copying the source folder structure as is to the destination even though only the container name is specified.

I just want files from the source to be copied to the destination folder directly instead of creating additional folder structure in it.

This is how my Azure file copy task looks like.

[image]

So, at the destination, it is creating "**QA**" folder inside "**assets**" container, which I don't want to get created.

[image]

**How can I prevent folder creation and deploy files directly to Azure storage container itself?**

Comment: Did you try specifying a wildcard, i.e. `path\to\stuff\QA\*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the source from `.../Assets/QA` to `.../Assets/QA/*`. Then the files in the folder QA will be uploaded to your container without creating QA folder.
[image]